# How can I tell what process or user is using PostgreSQL's template1 database?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a database on a customer's PostgreSQL 8.1 system (some old windows OS; I'm not sure which) (Yes, I know it's ancient, but it's working.).  It is telling that source database template1 is being accessed by another user.  The only users there should be on that system are the programs and scripts that my company provided.  I can create a database using template0, but I'd rather not, in case there's something important in template1 (which I doubt).  I don't want to restart the PostgreSQL service because that would interrupt production monitoring, although production would not be affected.

So, is there some way I can find what process is using the template1 database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to query `pg_stat_activity`.

```
SELECT *
       FROM pg_stat_activity
       WHERE datname = 'template1';
```

Comment: Thanks very much!  I killed the process that was sitting on it.  We'll see who screams.